# Getting information from another table in same query

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

actually i have 2 table the log table and the user table.

my current statement is working fine to get all logs in the inverse order

this is my current query

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT * FROM logs WHERE roomid = '$room' AND post_id > '$last' ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 100) AS log 
ORDER BY post_id ASC
```

here are the 2 table structure

logs table

date | user_logs_id | message | type

user table

user_id | avatar | color | ....

the goal for me is to keep the same order as i actually have with the query above but getting information avatar and color from user table matching to the user_logs_id

then now my problem is that i have field  user_logs_id in logs table and i want to retreive some information matching that user_logs_id from the user table

anyone can help me to solve that thanks

Comment: Might help if you provide table structure, sample data and expected results...  Sounds like you need to use a `join` though...

Comment: ok  here are the 2 table structure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between INNER and OUTER joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that user_logs_id  = user_id simply use a join

```
SELECT logs.*, user.color, user.avatar FROM logs 
JOIN user on user.user_id = logs.user_logs_id
WHERE logs.roomid = '$room' AND post_id > '$last' ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 100
```

**edit updated query to show specific fields

Comment: ok this seem to work but the only thing is it will require all the user information is it doable to only require avatar and color from user ?

Comment: If you mean you only what the color and avatar fields? then in your select use `user.color as 'color', user.avatar as 'avatar'`

Comment: hi, that wont work since color is not = to something specific it can be different from every user what i need is to get only avatar and color values from users table matching to the user_logs_id

Comment: or i might not understanding clearly where to add those user.color as 'color' for the query it work good like that but it will be more optimised selecting only desired field from user table

Comment: Hi I've updated the query in the original answer does this help?

Comment: `SELECT logs.*, user.avatar, user.avatar, user.user_name, users.user_id FROM logs, user WHERE user.user_id = logs.post_user AND logs.post_roomid = '$room' AND logs.post_id > '$last' ORDER BY logs.post_id ASC LIMIT 100`

Comment: both my version and your version works... i ask myself do the join is faster to execute than my version without a join ?

Comment: If it solves your problem then its fine. My personal preference is to use the join syntax as I find it easier to read also I often need to use different types of join (LEFT, RIGHT, OUTER, etc)

Comment: You are still creating a join with your syntax, its just not explicitly stated